# Missing JPA entity concept? Am I wrong to assume JPA entries will be saved to my existing database tables?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I don't know if I'm missing the JPA concept, but I 'assumed', the data would be saved and retrieved to and from an existing table in my database.

For instance, I assumed that if I was previously using JDBC to retrieve data from my MySQL database and displayed in my website, I could use JPA instead to do the same, but it doesn't seem to retrieve the existing data, it actually creates another local database and stores and retrieves data from there.

I know is not connecting, if that is what is supposed to do, because the index starts from 1, whereas my original table already has some records there. What gives?

The following msg is shown when executing from scratch:

> INFO: The backing store, C:\Users{blah\blah}\
>   war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It
>   will be created.

Using:

> Eclipse Jave EE, appengine, local dev mysql db and datanucleus. Other relevant
>   info is that I did not start this project as a JPA, just added
>   "datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar" to the build path.

There are actually no errors when creating and committing entities to db. Simplified, but relevant code follows...

The entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1147432247140914843L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="cat_id")
    private Long id;    // primary key

    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    public Category(String category) { this.category = category; }

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getCategory() { return category; }
    public void setCategory(String category) { this.category=category; }
}
```

The part that sets the correct connection params:

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:google:mysql://apengine_appid:master/master");               
} else {
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/master");
}
```

Insert test row:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu", properties);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Category cat = new Category("Category");
em.persist(cat);
//em.flush();
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Iterate inserted records as a test:

```
em = emf.createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<Category> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c", Category.class);
List<Category> results = query.getResultList();
for (Category c : results) {
   System.out.println(">>existing: Category(" + c.getId() + ", '" + c.getCategory() + "')");
}
```

Comment: And the log says ? because if using MySQL it will print out ALL SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't reviewed the log, but I'm getting there soon. Is there a complete example of an app that's trying to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: The DataNucleus docs has ample tutorials on basic JPA and RDBMS. Also using old/unsupported versions of DataNucleus JPA (3.2/3.3 are the supported ones) for RDBMS persistence is also a strange practice (3.1 is the only one that GAE/Datastore requires, and thats only because Google are too lazy at releasing updates); suggest you update

Comment: It sucks that there are no complete comprehensive examples! They always assume a lot of things as far as setup and whatnot. Most examples are fragmented and inconsistent. What's needed is a step-by-step example. What's so difficult about saying, you need so and so jars, add them to CLASSPATH, with these settings, blah blah blah... I started to make some progress putting 1+1 from different sources, not 100%, but getting there...

Comment: The DN tutorial for JPA + RDBMS http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/guides/tutorial_rdbms.html states what is needed to run it (and is a downloadable sample). The mature thing to do if you think something is missing is to report a problem with it to the project that wrote it then they can update it (but then we've run that tutorial with just the jars mentioned and all runs fine for us). If instead you're referring to Google's docs then suggest you raise that with them (and hope that you can get a response)

Answer (score 1):

from message

```
INFO: The backing store, C:\Users{blah\blah}\ war\WEB-INF\appengine-
generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.
```

i assumed that you using [Data Store](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) instead `mysql`. If you want to use your old mysql as your app data source, you can use [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/). You can back up your old database and restore it in Google Cloud SQL (AFAIK, You need to enable your billing to use this feature).

I used Eclipse Juno with Google Plugin and this is how to refer your database to your MySQL Server :

```
1. Right Click on your project -> Google -> App Engine Setting.
2. At Google Cloud SQL Part, tick enable Google Cloud SQL.
3. Configure your Development Connection.
```

I was tried Google Cloud SQL in the past but in the end, i just build new database with datastore because its easier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. No, I started using Google Cloud SQL for production and MySQL for local development tests from the beginning of my app. I have modified my original question with the lines that make the switch according to whether I'm running it locally or on google app-engine. According to examples, the same driver and URL used to connect via JDBC are used when using JPA. So I assumed (here I go again) that just doing it that way it would connect to same existing database, but using JPA instead.